# How do I navigate to an internal link and execute jquery function?

Tags: c#, jquery, hyperlink, navigation, href

I´m a very new to jquery.
I´m using this jquery code fragment and it´s working fine. But I would like to navigate from anywhere on the website and still have the function work:

```
    function showselectedbox(theselectedbox) {
        $(".pageboxes").each(function (index) {
            if ($(this).attr("id") == theselectedbox) {
                $(this).show(200);
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide(600);

            }
        });
    }
<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showselectedbox('mynewboxes1');" >show this one only</a>
<div class="pageboxes" id="mynewboxes1">Div #1</div>
<a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showselectedbox('mynewboxes2');" >show this one only</a>
<div class="pageboxes" id="mynewboxes1">Div #1</div>
```

... more of the same.

I also build a tabbed menu for the navigation, and would like the selected link marked.

```
<div id="metaltop-teal">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="first active"><a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showonlyone('mynewboxes1');" >show this one only</a></li>
                                <li><a id="myHeader2" href="javascript:showonlyone('mynewboxes2');" >show this one only</a></li>...
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Is there also another way to format the url? e.g: `<a href="url" ...>link to page</a>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should put your javascript in a .js file and then include the file in your other files:

```
 <script src="yourfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

now you can refer to your javascript function freely.

Remember to include your .js-file AFTER you include jquery, or your script won't work.

EDIT:

To have code execute upon pageload, I'd use $('document').ready() This ensures that the code isn't executed until all elements of the DOM is loaded. This way, you avoid trying to manipulate elements that aren't there. This is especially important when using eventhandlers such as click(). For live() and delegate() which also are attached to elements created later, this is not so important.

Firstly you make a line:

`$('document').ready(function(){`

after that line, you put anything to execute when the page is loaded.

To finish this block, you write

`});`

And after that you put your functions etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Atheist. Everything is set up fine, but what I ment is how to access page2.aspx from page1.aspx and apply: 'if ($(this).attr("id") == theselectedbox) {
                $(this).show(200);
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide(600);

            }' How can I also insert this script 'addClass("active")' to mark the active tab in the navigation? Thanks

Comment: I would set up an eventlistener using either [click()](api.jquery.com/click/) or [delegate()](api.jquery.com/delegate/). The difference is if your links are generated after pageload you'll have to use delegate, but if they're not generated using javascript, I'd use click():

Comment: Thanks for your effort to help me, but like I said, I´m very new and only know very jquery terms e.g .click(), .show(), .hide() and .toggle(). I was hoping that someone could help me rewrite the above function so that it includes '$('document').ready(function(){' and change the format of the link e.g from '<a id="myHeader1" href="javascript:showselectedbox('mynewboxes1');" >' to '<a href="url or # or url#mynewboxes1">page</a>'. Thanks again.